# Is accessing the same array address repeatedly both spatial and temporal locality?

Tags: architecture, spatial, cpu-architecture, temporal

So I'm having questions about whether or not this portion of code has any spatial locality at all. I have a strong feeling it does have temporal locality. A peer of mine says there is some spatial locality, but I feel like it does not have spatial locality. The portion of code is this:

```
for (i = 0; i < S; i++) {
read A[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spatial locality refers to accessing near by memory locations. In your example, the array is always indexed by a constant, hence will only access one memory location (to be precise it will access the cache line aligned address of the array index). Therefore it only has temporal locality.